# Setting up Session variable in Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

Hi I'm very new with ColdFusion 10 especially with Application.cfc. It is very confusing.
I created Application.cfc and inside this cfc I created the following:

My questions are:
  1. Why do I get session error? (see my codes below) 
  2. What should I put in sessionEnd function?

```
  <!--- Application.cfc --->
   <CFCOMPONENT displayname="Application" output="true">

     <cfset THIS.Name = "MyTestApp" />
     <cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,60,0) />
     <cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
     <cfset THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 0, 30, 0 ) />
     <cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />

    <cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />

    <cffunction name="OnApplicationStart" access="public" 
                                          returntype="boolean" output="false">

       <cfset application.Main_DSN = "MyTestDB">

    </cffunction>



    <cffunction name="onApplicationEnd" output="false"> 
       <cfargument name="applicationScope" required="true">

    </cffunction>


    <cffunction name="OnSessionStart" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" 
                                         hint="Fires when user session initializes">

       <cfset session.loggedin = "NO">
       <cfset session.username = "">
       <cfset session.userrights = "">
       <cfset session.usergroup = "">  

  </cffunction>


 <!--- After user login, I have checklogin.cfm --->
 <cfif mylogin NEQ true><!--- Login failed, go redirect to login page --->
    <cflocation url="login.cfm"> 
 <cfelse>
       <cfset session.loggedin = "YES"><!--- ??? error: see below --->
   <cfset session.username = "#Trim(Form.username)#">
   <cfset session.userrights = "#Trim(Form.userrights )#">
   <cfset session.usergroup = "#Trim(Form.usergroup)#">     
 </cfif>

 <cffunction name="onSessionEnd">

    <!--- Not sure what can I put in here????? --->    

 </cffunction>
```

Comment: You don't have to put anything into onSessionEnd(). It's there in case you want to perform some actions when your session times out. Some people will save session data to a DB or to disk when session times out, then picks it back up on the next user login so they can pick up where they left off.

Comment: You might want to check out this tutorial on Application.cfc: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-coldfusion-application-cfc-tutorial-and-application-cfc-reference.htm

Comment: I'm sorry!! The error that I got after a successful login is: Element LOGGEDIN is undefined in SESSION. But actually I have declared it in the OnsessionStart function. I declared several session variables in OnsessionStart. Once I'm successfully logged in I should be able to assign values to these session variables. This is my understanding. So far, that is my only problem, CF does not detect session.LoggedIn, yes, it seems like OnSessionStart is not firing, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: OK, as you explained that as soon as the application starts the OnsessionStart should have fired . I did some testing and put cfdump for all of my session variables in the login form (one of them is cfset session.loggedIn = "No"). When I click on login form, before I even start login in, I can see my session variables!!! I can see my session variables got initialized, the session.LoggedIn value is "No". Now the not so good news is, when I assigned session.loggedIn="Yes" after a successful login I still get the same " Element LOGGEDIN is undefined in SESSION.",  I don't understand.

Comment: mkross1983, thank you for taking the time to respond and help me. Here how it goes: My login codes are not in OnsessionStart or any function. The login form post to checklogin.cfm. Login validation is done in checklogin.cfm. Here, once user is validated, I assigned values to those sessions variables that I have previously set in OnsessionStart function but the error says that Element LOGGEDIN is undefined in SESSION. In OnSessionStart I set <cfset session.loggedIn = "No"> that's it. On checklogin.cfm I assign "YES" when user is successfully validated.

Comment: Is the block of code that comes underneath "<!--- After user login, I have checklogin.cfm --->" part of Application.cfc or a .cfm file somewhere in your application?

Comment: Do you have other Application.cfc/Application.cfm files in the site?

Answer (score 2):

Your login code is outside any of the event handlers in your Application.cfc file, so that code will run first... before any of the event handlers!

The execution sequence of code in Application.cfc is:

- code outside of any event handler (irrespective of where it is in the file)
- onApplicationStart()
- onSessionStart()
- onRequestStart()
- etc

So you cannot have code referencing the session scope (or application scope for that matter) outside the other event handlers. You can only start using session variables once `onSessionStart()` has fired. Not before.

Comment: I think that the question has code listings that are out of order.  They reference checklogin.cfm in the code comments, but then start listing more Application.cfc.  At least that's my interpretation of it...

Comment: It's definitely possible, but I have to go on only what the person posts. I'll revise if we get clearer info. Basically I'm answering the question as asked, which is perhaps not how the person ought to be asking it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message that you are getting?

You can really put anything in the session end.  Anything that you would need to run to clean up after a session.

Maybe you want to update a log or send an email, clear a cookie, or redirect to a certain page.

**EDIT:**

Is everything else in the Application.cfc working for you?  It seems like the onSessionStart event is not firing.

**EDIT 2:***
Sorry for doing this via an answer but I need more rep to leave comments.

The session should start as soon as you connect to the application, you do not need to wait to be "logged in" as in verify credentials.

If the session variables do not exist then the event is not firing for some reason.  Make sure you have the file name correctly and it is in the root folder of the application.

**EDIT 3:**
Your login code is not in the onSessionStart function, not in any function.  Unless I misunderstood your comment and you were saying that code section is in the "checklogin.cfm" file and not in the Application.cfc file.

**EDIT 4:**
I need to jump on a client call but I can help some more after.  We might need to take a look at part of the checklogin.cfm file.

**EDIT 5:**
Any luck?

**EDIT 6:**
Sorry for the delay, volume is ramping up this afternoon.

At this point I think I would either need to see the code that is doing the validation checking or ask if you are sure the validation is working correctly.

I assume you are connecting to a database, if you take the query you are using to verify the login credentials and run it in SQL server or whatnot inserting the values you would type into the form, do you get any results?

**EDIT 7:**
Figure it out, OP?

Comment: I just posted my explanation above

Comment: So I set session.loggedin="NO" inside OnSessionStart function then after user is successfully validated I assign that session.loggedIn to "Yes" but CF throws error saying " Element LOGGEDIN is undefined in SESSION.". It's been defined in OnSessionStart isn't it?

Comment: mkross1983, I'm sorry for not able to respond last week. Yes, db connection if fine,dumped out the result and can see  the query result. It is just when I cfset session.loggedIn = "yes" CF is throwing error. Can I email you my codes so you can see them? there is no place for me to show my codes here.

Comment: I'd love to help with the code but not sure how to send you a direct message on here.  I'll look into it.

Comment: Seems like SO doesn't allow for it.  I'll set up a throw away account and expect it to be spammed like crazy but that's alright.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: mkross1983, if you like, you can email me at megawatilukito@yahoo.com

Comment: I'm not too sure I follow you regarding sending private message to each other. It can't be done through this forum?

Comment: Nope, I sent you an email this morning though.